# Buttons intercepting commands for game

Tags: c#, winforms, button, focus, controls

I have made a simple game in winforms using c# as my final project for my c# course in high school.

The game is complete but I just want to add some minor features such as buttons to reset and change mode etc. But when i add these buttons they take "control" of the arrow keys and my 'player' doesn't respond to arrow keys anymore since that moves the focus from 1 button to another.

You know when they turn light-blue and are "marked".

So stack, how do i fix this?

Edit for clarification:

Player moves perfectly when no buttons are on the form or "button1.enabled = false;"
Player doenst move at all when a button is added onto the form from the tool box or "button1.enabled = true;",

Player doesnt move when buttons are on the form since the arrow keys used to control player is now used to 'scroll' through buttons and highlight then.

Edit2:

This is what i mean by highlighted or marked. The arrow keys just shift the marking from button 1 to button 2. http://puu.sh/8bmn2.png

Comment: We would need to see an example of what you mean. Your problem is that the button is taking Focus, and you could try `this.Focus()` as the last line in a button handler to give focus back to the form. But without a short example, it is hard to give a solution.

Comment: I could upload the .exe for you and you could see what i mean?

Comment: You can't upload files here, and we don't want you uploading to another site to link here. We need a [short minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what is wrong.

Comment: Try setting "TabStop" on the buttons to false. This is a duplicate of a question somewhere, I'll link if I can find it...

Comment: Ok i will edit main post.

Comment: I've googled alot and searched here. Didnt know the keyword 'Focus'. Still cant find anything. @LordTakkera TabStop to false didnt work i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button`s are most likely stealing focus away from your `Form`.

As an alternative, if you're not hung up on using buttons, you could add a `MenuStrip` to your `Form` and add menu items for *"Reset"*, *"Change Mode"*, etc.

When your user closes the menu, focus should return to the form. It has the advantage of getting the options out of the way too, instead of cluttering up the screen with multiple buttons.

Comment: Im not familiar with how MenuStrips work, might look into it tho. Thank you!

Comment: MenuStrip fixed the problem. Thank you Grant!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preview events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle the key presses you care about and override their focus-changing behavior:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetPreviewKeyDownToAllControls(this.Controls);    
}

private void SetPreviewKeyDownToAllControls(Control.ControlCollection cc)
{
    if (cc != null)
    {
        foreach (Control control in cc)
        {
            control.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(control_PreviewKeyDown);
            SetPreviewKeyDownToAllControls(control.Controls);
        }
    }
}

void control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives me error for 'SetFeatureToAllControls'. I am a c# beginner might i be missing something?

Comment: Doesnt work I'm afraid. This does make it so the highlight from button 1 doesnt change to button 2 when any arrowkey is pressed but still player isnt moving. Worth to mention is that player is a label?

Comment: Where are you listening for the arrow events to move the player? It's possible that my code is suppressing your event handler.

Comment: With bools and a timer using if (right = true) player.left += 5;